# Saving PDF into Attachment Object

Tags: custom-object, data-loader, attachment, pdf

I am looking for advice on the best direction to go in.

A little background:

On a custom page a user can generate a report. Every time a report is generated, a unique PDF is saved into document storage. My task: I need to take this PDF and add it to the Attachment object. What is the best way of going about this?
Is there a way to do this without using dataloader? My thought was to create a new attachment and update the field values:

```
Attachment att = new Attachment();
att.Name = BVS__c.CompanyName__c;
att.Body = BVS__c.Report__c;
att.ParentId = Contact.Id;
insert att;
```

But I am getting rejected from doing so. Is this possible? Or is it better to go with DataLoader?

Comment: What is the data type of BVS__c.Report__c

Comment: @Ashwani BCS__c is a custom object and Report__c is a field on the object with the type of Long Text Area. This field stores a link to view the PDF. An example of the data that would be stored in the field is: `file://00.0.0.00/DocumentStorage/prod/B%20V/2016/11/17/B%20ID%20-%20Company%20Name%20Here.PDF`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `BVS__c.Report__c` is long text area, program would throw exception.

The field `att.Body` only except data type of `Blob`. 
I believe you need to get the PDF from document storage and assign to Attachment object's `Body` field something like that:-

```
Attachment att = new Attachment();
att.Name = BVS__c.CompanyName__c;
att.Body = documentObjectRecord.Body;
att.ParentId = Contact.Id;
insert att;
```

Here `documentObjectRecord` is the object where PDF is stored and `Body` is a field which has data type of `Blob`.

As per the comment it looks like an external link. So, first get the document by call-out or just by `Pagereference.getContent();` method. Make sure you add the base URL in `RemoteSite` settings.